# Conditional independence conjecture

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, sufficient-statistics, conditioning

Suppose there are four random variables (events), $A$, $B$, $C$ and $X$. If we have $X\perp A|B$, saying $X$ and $A$ are conditional independent given $B$, then I want to ask that whether we have $X\perp (A,C)|(B,C)$?

Intuitively, if $X\perp A|B$, then we can say $B$ contains all the information about $X|A$ (thinking of the concept of sufficient statistics), it seems to be reasonable that $(B,C)$ contains all the information about $X|(A,C)$, yes?

But I am not sure... Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking if X⊥A |B implies X⊥(A,C) | (B,C)? If so, this is not the case. The reason is that X⊥(A,C) | (B,C) implies X⊥A | (B,C), but this can not necessarily implied by X⊥A |B.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I asked. Then what if $B\perp C$?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is still possible that X⊥(A,C) | (B,C) does not hold.

Comment: A useful tool are the graphoid axioms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphoid). The first 4 hold for all probability distributions. Note that they do not completely characterize all conditional independencies.